# Creating an App Engine Connected Android Project with Python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

I find a seemingly simple [app engine tutorial for creating an android app with a java backend](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae). Does app engine have tutorials for using Python instead of Java? I have not been able to find one. Even if there is no simple python plugin as there is for Java, is anyone aware of something that is very close to the apparent simplicity of the java plugin that appEngine is offering?

Comment: Have a look at : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

App Engine has lots of tutorials and material for Python developers, but they do not have a Python equivalent of what you listed.

That's OK though, because that is rather dated anyway.  The new way of connecting App Engine to Android (or iOS or web) clients is via their endpoints service/code generator, and that works equally well with Python or Java.